# how to get Network mapped drive VolumeLabel in C#?

Tags: c#

So for example, if i have drive Z:NetworkDrive, which mapped to shared folder on another server, and i want to return volumelabel "NetworkDrive". Next code seems to work:

```
 foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
            {
                if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Network)
                    mappedDrivesNames.Add(drive.VolumeLabel);
            }
```

But it return the name of the first shared folder from the list on server. Any ideas, why this happened?

Comment: Interesting question. "Network Drive" isn't the label of the drive. Windows Explorer shows "Network Drive" as the drive's type. In a command box, the `label z:` command would show the actual label of the volume the drive is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

If I just code

```
var drive = new DriveInfo("Z");
Console.WriteLine(drive.VolumeLabel);
```

It is showing me the Label of the Volume the network share is on. I have my drive Z: connected to a share on a Windows XP computer and the share is on a NTFS formatted drive. If I remove the label for that volume, the program will output an empty line.

I don't know what the expected result should be if the share is on a Linux machine. I don't know if Linux has something like a Label, but I don't think so.